# HTML Help (Adding Picture and & Rotation)

Tags: html, css

I'm just free styling right now. I downloaded a free HTML editor and just playing around. What I'm really trying to do is add a picture and rotate it to the right by 30 degrees, add a round corner by 45px, and blue shadow by 20px.

This is what I have so far, again I'm just free styling. I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. This is my first time playing with HTML...

```
  Author: ...
  Date:   04/15/2014

  Filename:         t78.htm
  Supporting files: torte.jpg

-->

    <TITLE> ...???... </TITLE>
    <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
    <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
```

```
<img src="torte.jpg" data-rotate="90">
    <img src="torte.jpg" data-rotate="45">
    <img src="torte.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see to rotate either u can use jquery or CSS..

lets see how to do it with CSS

[check the link](http://jsfiddle.net/g7FtY/2/)

--CSS--

```
img
{
    display:block;
    margin:100px;  
    /*set the radius as u want*/
    border-radius:45px;
    /*set the shadow u want*/
    box-shadow:10px 10px 20px blue;
}
```

-- declare a css class to rotate 30 degree clockwise..

```
.clock30
{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

check the link you will know how to use it
http://jsfiddle.net/g7FtY/2/

Answer (score 1):

Check this out [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/programmer101/x3559/). hope this helps.

add this to your CSS for image rotation

```
   /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    /* IE9 */
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
```

and this to your CSS for radius and shadow

```
 border-radius:45px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

Answer (score 0):

hello you can use CSS to achieve the rotate style.

```
<img class="rotate" img src="torte.jpg" />
<style>
.rotate {

/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

}
</style>
```

Comment: Is it possible to rotate a image in HTML?

Comment: HTML5, Javascript and CSS is the only way, i think.

Comment: if you want to put style into a html element you need CSS, there are bunch of tutorials for you to read and easily adopt.

Comment: you can use the code i provided to fix your problem.